# System.IO.Packaging part size

Tags: .net, package

Is there some way to get the byte length of a System.IO.Package.PackagePart? (other than reading the entire stream).

Comment: Do you want the compressed or the uncompressed size?

Comment: Why doesn't `part.GetStream().Length` work ?  Does this walk the entire stream via `Seek`?

Comment: @0xa3 uncompressed. @Steve I didn't know it was there!